# Get Ambiguous method with enum parameters

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to invoke a method from a dynamically loaded assembly.
The method is ambiguous.

For example:
The dll contains the following methods:

```
public static string ReadString(string key, KeyType type)
public static string ReadString(string key, string type)
```

I would like to invoke the one with the enum parameter **KeyType**.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"stringutils.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("Utils.StringReader");
```

I tried

```
var method = type.GetMethod("ReadString", new[] { typeof(string) });
```

And tried

```
var method = type.GetMethod("ReadString", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) });
```

But it returns null

Comment: Did you try `typeof(KeyType)` instead of `typeof(int)`?

Comment: But KeyType is declared and defined in that dll.

Comment: `type.GetMethod("ReadString", new[] { typeof(string), assembly.GetType("KeyType") });`?

Comment: assembly.GetType("KeyType") returns null. even if I put the full namespace path

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the type of the enum with `GetType(...)`, but you might need to include the namespace, and it requires `KeyType` to reside in the assembly you are loading.

You could also use `GetMethods()` and filter the methods according to any arbitrary criteria. Example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
public enum MyEnum
{
    Test1,
    Test2
}
class Program
{
    public static void MyMethod(MyEnum i) => Console.WriteLine($"My Method With {i}");
    public static void MyMethod() => Console.WriteLine("My Method Without Enum");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var enumType = asm
            .GetType("MyNamespace.MyEnum");

        var method1 = asm
            .GetType("MyNamespace.Program")
            .GetMethod("MyMethod", new[] { enumType });

        var method2 = asm.GetType("MyNamespace.Program")
            .GetMethods()
            .First(
                m => m.IsStatic &&
                m.IsPublic &&
                m.Name == "MyMethod" &&
                m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);

        var myEnumValue = Enum.ToObject(enumType, 1);
        method1.Invoke(null, new object[] { myEnumValue });
    }
}
}
```

Would output `My Method With Test2`